# Comparing 1x Xeon multi core vs 4x UltraSparc IV

Tags: performance, memory, central-processing-unit, sun

I'm in the process of reviewing specs for hardware running an Oracle server.

The new hardware will be running using Xeon processor compared to the old servers (Solaris) running on UltraSparc IV.

So the comparison is:

***1x*** **Intel Xeon E5-2697 v3** vs ***4x*** **Sun Microsystems UltraSparc IV 1.35 GHz**

The single CPU vs CPU is obvious, but the current spec has 4 sockets with 4x UltraSparc CPUs.

It's presumably not a simple case of aggregating clock speeds, but was wondering how multi-cpu compares with multi-core modern CPU with greater clock speed.

I've found this comparison for single CPU:

http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/350/Intel_Xeon_E5-2697_v2_vs_Sun_Microsystems_UltraSparc_IV_1.35_GHz_(SME1167ALGA-1350).html

Any tips on how to compare the two?  Obviously memory speeds, capacity would be greater in newer architecture also?

TIA

Comment: You've found a comparison chart,what more do you want?

Comment: I'm really trying to find out how 4x ultrasparcs compare to 1x 4 core xeon with multithreading